# Can't write files on android

Tags: android, permissions

Getting really frustrated with this. Here's my code:

```
public class FileIO {
    public static void writeString(FileOutputStream out, String target) throws IOException {
        target += "\n";
        for ( int i = 0; i < target.length(); i ++ ) {
            out.write(target.charAt(i));
        }
        out.flush();
    }


    public static void copy(File src, File dst) throws IOException {
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(src);
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dst);

        // Transfer bytes from in to out
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int len;
        while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
            out.write(buf, 0, len);
        }
        in.close();
        out.close();
    }


    public static void createFile(String path) throws IOException {
        File f = new File(path);
        if ( !f.exists() )
            f.createNewFile();
    }
}
```

And out of desperation, I added this into my manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_SUPERUSER" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BATTERY_STATS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CLEAR_APP_CACHE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.EXPAND_STATUS_BAR" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_PACKAGE_SIZE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_FORMAT_FILESYSTEMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_STATS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_MMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_WAP_PUSH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REORDER_TASKS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RESTART_PACKAGES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_ALARM" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_ALWAYS_FINISH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_ANIMATION_SCALE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_DEBUG_APP" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_PROCESS_LIMIT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_TIME_ZONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER_HINTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SIGNAL_PERSISTENT_PROCESSES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SUBSCRIBED_FEEDS_READ" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SUBSCRIBED_FEEDS_WRITE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_SIP" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PERSISTENT_ACTIVITY"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.browser.permission.READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SOCIAL_STREAM"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_USER_DICTIONARY"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.browser.permission.WRITE_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_PROFILE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SOCIAL_STREAM"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_USER_DICTIONARY"/>
```

and this code says that i DO have the required permissions to write:

```
String permission = "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE";
        int res = c.checkCallingOrSelfPermission(permission);
        Debug.log("WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE: " + (res == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED));
```

But still, I get this:

```
06-23 20:50:35.709: W/System.err(5722): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard/package.zip (Permission denied)
```

and its not only on this file, i just cant read/write ANYTHING on the sd card, and if that wasnt enough, i cant access the internet, I use the GMailSender and it logs this:

> 06-23 20:50:35.809: I/Adnan(5722): javax.mail.MessagingException:
>   Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 465; 06-23
>   20:50:35.809: I/Adnan(5722):   nested exception is: 06-23
>   20:50:35.809: I/Adnan(5722):  java.net.SocketException: Permission
>   denied

But as you can see in the wall of permissions I added the INTERNET as well. Anyone can enlighten me what's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error isn't related to android permissions. It's a file system permission error. It means that you don't have write permissions for this folder in your SD card.

It usually happens when the USB storage is enabled. Try to run your code when your device isn't connected to your computer.

Comment: You are right, i created 2 emulators and it works there, but in my real phone it just wont read/write or access the internet, guess my phone started to play weird and blocked it. But thanks i finally resolved it! I would've spent an eternity trying to fix it thinking its a permission error.

Comment: This is not quire correct.  USB storage enabled would not mean that the SD card is mounted read only, rather it would mean *that the USB storage is not mounted at all*.  Also, this does not explain the lack of ability access the network.

Answer (score 0):

In my applications that access the sdcard, /mnt is not in the path. Try removing it.

Also, it would be helpful to know if you are testing with a real device or the emulator.

Comment: real device with a 2GB sd card.

Comment: and i didnt put the mnt in the path, i used the Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()